# Automated Getter/Setter Functions

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm looking at Doctrine 2 and Symfony documentation for creating a model class.There are several code snippets where a getProperty and setProperty is used within the class, and these are somehow used automatically when a value is assigned directly to the property. This is different then the typical get/set magic methods, and the sample code I have come across does not implement any custom magic methods, so I believe this is handled by Doctrine somewhere.

From what I've read, Doctrine implements accessors and mutators. Maybe I missed a package when downloading Pear, or maybe I'm not including something in my script.

For example:

```
class User {

    public $name;
    public function getName()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

$user = new User();
$foo = $user->name; // getName is called
```

Note: I'm looking for a Doctrine specific solution. I know this can be done in someway with PHP, but I want to use Doctrine's native functions.

Edit: Updated to clarify how this differs from typical get/set magic methods, and note.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class User {
    private $name;
    public function __get($property) {
        $methodName = "get".ucfirst($property);
        if (method_exists($this, $methodName)) {
           return call_user_func(array($this, $methodName));
        } elseif (isset($this->{$property})) {
            return $this->{$property};
        }
        return null;
    }
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $methodName = "set".ucfirst($property);
        if (method_exists($this, $methodName)) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$methodName), array($value));
        } else {
            $this->{$property} = $value;
        }
    }
    public function getName() {
        return "My name is ".$this->name;
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->name = "Foo";
$bar = $user->name;
echo $bar; // "My name is Foo"
```

If there is a method `getSomething` or `setSomething` it will be called when accessing the properties directly.

As I read in [this documentation page](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/pl/introduction-to-models), it is exactly what the code above does what Doctrine does. But it calls the method `_set('fieldName', 'value')`.

Comment: I'll try extending my class with Doctrine_Record and see if that will do the trick.

Comment: Apparently Doctrine 2 was redesigned from 1.x, and the get/set needs to be setup manually. The examples and doc reference helped me confirm this, thanks!

Comment: Would this code work in Doctrine 2? I really don't want to write all the getters and setters manually

Answer (score 2):

If `$name` is declared `public` then this line of code:

```
$foo = $user->name;
```

is actually accessing the `$name` field, and is not in fact calling the `getName` function.

You can use PHP's magic `__get` and `__set` methods to automagically provide accessors and mutators, like this:

```
class User {
    private $name;
    public function __get($property) {
       //check first to make sure that $property exists 
       return $this->$property;
    }
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        //check first to make sure that $property exists
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->name = "Foo";
$bar = $user->name;
echo $bar; //"Foo"
```

You can find more info about PHP's magic methods [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

**UPDATE**: This is what I think Doctrine is doing:

```
class User {
    private $name;
    public function __get($property) {
       $propertyTitleCase = mb_convert_case($property, MB_CASE_TITLE);
       $method = "get{$propertyTitleCase}";
       if(method_exists($this, $method))
       {
          return $this->$method();
       }
       else {
          return $this->$property;
       }
    }

    public function getName() {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not actually calling getName and setName in this code

Comment: I know that. `getName` and `setName` are not even defined in my code.

Comment: Right, that's my understanding of the typical get/set magic methods. I should have explained that in my initial post. I believe Doctrine has the ability to add its own magic, where getName is called automatically, but this is not working for me. So I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @Shroder Oh, ok, I wasn't sure if you knew about magic methods already. I'm not aware of another way to implement the kind of functionality you're talking about (where `$obj->property` resolves in a call to `$obj->getProperty()`), but I'm sure it's possible. I've seen things you can't even imagine (both good and bad) done w/ PHP.